# 「javac ファイルが見つかりません」というエラーが発生する

Tags: java

プログラミング始めたてです
HelloWorldの文字を作りたいのですが下の様に表記が出てしまいうまく進めません

**エラーメッセージ**

```
javac: ファイルが見つかりません: HelloWorld.java
使用方法: javac <options><source files>
使用可能なオプションのリストについては、-helpを使用します
```

**ファイルの内容**

```
class HelloWorld
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello! I'm LinuxAcademy");
    }
}
```

解決策募集してますm(_ _)m

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　エラーが起きたときに打ち込んだコマンド自体の情報もあると嬉しいです。

Comment: @55Rihito さん> もし既存の回答によって問題が解決した場合は、その回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックし、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javacコマンドがHelloWorld.javaを見つけられない。
作業環境のミスです

```
C:\Users\shupe\dev\workspace>tree /f
フォルダー パスの一覧
ボリューム シリアル番号は 040A-CD23 です
C:.
└─src
    └─main
        └─java
                HelloWorld.java

REM NGパターン
C:\Users\shupe\dev\workspace>javac HelloWorld.java
javac: ファイルが見つかりません: HelloWorld.java
使用方法: javac <options> <source files>
使用可能なオプションのリストについては、-helpを使用します

REM OKパターン
C:\Users\shupe\dev\workspace>javac src\main\java\HelloWorld.java
C:\Users\shupe\dev\workspace>set classpath=src\main\java
C:\Users\shupe\dev\workspace>echo %classpath%
src\main\java
C:\Users\shupe\dev\workspace>java -classpath %classpath% HelloWorld
Hello! I'm LinuxAcademy
```

それと、提示のプログラムでは `{` が足りてないです。

Comment: ＠あとわいと　さん解答ありがとうございます。自分のコマンドプロンプトには次のように表記されているのですが```C:\Users\wande>　ドライブCのボリュームラベルはWindowsです　ボリュームシリアル番号は5C92-D5A3 です```　このC:以下とシリアル番号を変更したらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 実体にあわせて変更してください。その際ファイルシステム上どこにファイルを作ったのかを確認し、正しい値を利用しなくてはいけません。

Comment: C:以下を変更したら解決できました！ファイルの場所をきちんと把握できてなかったのが原因でした。解答ありがとうございます